# How to add footer to Navigation Drawer in Android using design support library?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can I add a footer to a `NavigationView`? In my case the `NavigationView` items are inflated by menu resource. Initially I tried to add a LinearLayout as a footer, but the `NavigationView` is not scrollable and the footer gets overlapped by the navigation menu items. I want to implement a Google Play rating segment as a footer exactly like this image:

[image]

`navigation_drawer.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:title="@string/app_name" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/green"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

It's really simple:

just wrap the desired footer in your NavigationView. You can use mine as an example - works like a charm!

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_footer_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Your Footer Text Here" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

You can use any (more or less complex) layout that way.
(Afaik this footer won't scroll and will be fixed).

Comment: on small screens (and/or in land orientation) the NavigationView's menu will overlap the footer - tried it with a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NavigationView](http://blog.nitish.io/post/122633295558/android-design-library-navigationview-with-footer)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Activity content goes here -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer_bottom" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

http://answermega.livedoor.biz/archives/1038944871.html

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign

Comment: This is working, but the bottom drawer is above the top one, so you have to add dummy items to it.

Comment: how to handle scroll, menu items are now hidden behind this view.

Comment: How to remove horizontal elevation from inner navigation view?

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_footer_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Your Footer Text Here" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

And for performing click on it:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
TextView footerTV = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_footer_textview);
footerTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Footer is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you add some information as to how this differs from the other answers?